# Better or optimized way to filter customer records by 3 dropdown filters

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, linq, optimization

I have one page name as:**CustomerList.aspx** on which i am displaying list of customers.

This is my table and class files too:

```
public partial class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerLocation { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public bool Removed { get; set; }
        public DateTime SubscribeDate { get; set; }
        public Location _Location;
    }

    public partial class Location
    {
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

> Inactive=true:Means customer is active in the system.
> Inactive=false:Means customer is inactive in the system.
>
> Removed=true:Means customer is removed from the system
>
> Removed=false:Means customer is not removed from the system.

I will provide user with 3 filters to filter customer records.

1)**Location Dropdown**

```
<select>
<option Text="All" Value="0" selected="true">
<option Text="London" Value="1">
<option Text="America" Value="2">
</select>
```

2)**Status Dropdown** with Value:All,Active,Inactive:

```
<select>
<option Text="All" Value="0" selected="true">
<option Text="Active" Value="1">
<option Text="Inactive" Value="2">
</select>
```

3)**Stats Data Dropdown**:

```
<select>
<option Text="All" Value="all" selected="true">
<option Text="Active Customers" Value="all">
<option Text="Recent subscribe customers" Value="subscribe">
<option Text="Recent unsubscribe customers" Value="unsubscribe">
</select>
```

As my page is loaded i want to display customers list in my grid.

This is my code:

```
 public void DisplayCustomersList()
        {
           DataTable list=GetCustomers(Convert.ToInt16(ddlLocation.SelectedValue),Convert.ToInt16(ddlStatus.SelectedValue),ddlstats.SelectedValue);
           Grid1.DataSource = list;
           Grid1.DataBind();
        }


  public DataTable GetCustomers(int LocationId, int ActiveId, string stats)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                var data = from c in context.Customers
                           where c.Removed == false
                           select new
                           {
                               FullName = c.FullName,
                               c.CustomerID,
                               c._Location.Name,
                               c.IsActive,
                               c.SubscribeDate,
                               c.Removed
                           };
                if (LocationId != 0 && ActiveId != 0)
                {
                    if (ActiveId == 1)
                    {
                        return
                            MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false));
                    }
                    else if(ActiveId==2)
                    {
                        return
                           MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                               data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == false && x.Removed == false));
                    }
                    return
                        MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                            data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.Removed==false));
                }

                if (LocationId != 0 && stats != "")
                {
                    if (stats == "all")
                    {
                        return
                            MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false));
                    }
                    else if (stats == "subscribe")
                    {
                        return
                           MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                               data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.LocationId==LocationId));
                    }
                }

                if (ActiveId != 0 && stats != "")
                {
                    if(ActiveId==1)
                    {
                        if(stats=="all")
                        {
                            return
                            MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == true) || (x.Removed == false) || (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false)));
                        }
                        else if (stats == "subscribe")
                        {
                            return
                               MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == true));
                        }
                        else if (stats == "unsubscribe")
                        {
                            return
                              MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                  data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
                        }
                        
                    }
                    else if(ActiveId==2)
                    {
                        if (stats == "all")
                        {
                            MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false) && (x.Removed == false)));
                        }
                        else if (stats == "subscribe")
                        {
                            return
                               MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
                        }
                        else if (stats == "unsubscribe")
                        {
                            return
                              MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                  data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (stats != "")
                {
                    if (stats == "all")
                    {
                        return
                            MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                                data.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false));
                    }
                    else if (stats == "subscribe")
                    {
                        return
                           MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                               data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive==true));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return
                       MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                           data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.IsActive == false && x.Removed == false));
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

On all `3 dropdown selected index change event` i am just calling this function like this:`DisplayCustomersList()`

So i just want to ask you that is this a proper way to perform filters or this code can be optimize in a better way.

can anybody provide me better solution or optimize this code in better way if possible???

Comment: If you use EF on top of the database you can use linq to entities queries wit ha projection to do all of this in the db and only return a collection of view model objects, it's quite a big shit but it retires most of the code and will seriously improve performance as you would be taking advantage of SQL servers advanced querying engine

Comment: @Wardy:I am using LinqtoSql and not Entity framework

Comment: I know ... my comment was a suggestion if you had the time to refactor since the net gains are immense, that said i'm sure it's possible to hack something similar together without EF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem can be optimized without `PredicateBuilder`, but it requires careful and "systematic" analysis.

---

#### To begin with... Consider Your Predicate Making Determining Factor

Consider your case, putting all 14 of them together like this, you actually can see that you only have **three** determining factors, namely: `LocationId`, `ActiveId`, and `stats`:

```
No  LocationId  ActiveId    stats       result
1   not 0       1           don't care  data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false)
2   not 0       2           don't care  data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == false && x.Removed == false));
3   not 0       not 0-2     don't care  data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.Removed == false));
4   not 0       don't care  all         data.Where(x => x.LocationId == LocationId && x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false)
5   not 0       don't care  subscribe   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.LocationId == LocationId));
6   don't care  1           all         data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == true) || (x.Removed == false) || (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false)));
7   don't care  1           subscribe   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == true));
8   don't care  1           unsubscribe data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
9   don't care  2           all         data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false) && (x.Removed == false)));
10  don't care  2           subscribe   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
11  don't care  2           unsubscribe data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
12  don't care  don't care  all         data.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && x.Removed == false));
13  don't care  don't care  subscribe   data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == true));
14  don't care  don't care  unsubscribe data.Where(x => x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) && x.Removed == false && x.IsActive == false));
```

---

#### Next, consider the pattern of your results

I observe that your result is quite deterministic with small exceptions. Apart from result no `6` and no `9`, your query predicates can actually be separated into **four** basic components (`6` and `9` omitted). They are:

```
comp1: x.LocationId == LocationId
comp2: x.IsRemoved == false
comp3: x.IsActive == true
comp4: x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)
```

And the query logic is simply:

```
comp1 && comp2 && comp3 && comp4
```

Putting them together with the 12 cases (excluding the cases `6` and `9`), you would get:

```
Simplification:
DC = don't care
A = applied
NA = not applied

                                        QueryComponents
No  LocationId  ActiveId    stats       comp1   comp2   comp3   comp4
1   not 0       1           DC          A       A       Yes     NA
2   not 0       2           DC          A       A       No      NA
3   not 0       not 0-2     DC          A       A       NA      NA
4   not 0       DC          all         A       A       Yes     NA
5   not 0       DC          subscribe   A       A       NA      A
7   DC          1           subscribe   NA      A       Yes     A
8   DC          1           unsubscribe NA      A       No      A
10  DC          2           subscribe   NA      A       No      A
11  DC          2           unsubscribe NA      A       No      A
12  DC          DC          all         NA      A       Yes     A
13  DC          DC          subscribe   NA      A       Yes     A
14  DC          DC          unsubscribe NA      A       No      A
```

---

#### After all the breaking down, we can see the Mapping

Now, it can be seen that the query components can be mapped back together with the determining factors:

```
comp1: Applied only when LocationId is not 0
comp2: Always applied //this is very good!
comp3: Yes = 1, 4, 7, 12, 13; NA = 3, 5; No = 2, 8, 10, 11, 14
comp4: Not Applied when LocationId is 0 except on case 5
```

---

#### You can start translating the concept into codes...

Thus, we can make some helping **flags** (there are 4 of them) to determine if a query component should be included or not, like this:

```
bool LocationIdNotApplied = LocationId == 0; //for comp1
bool IsActiveNotApplied = LocationId != 0 && (ActiveId < 0 || ActiveId > 2 || stats = "subscribe"); //for comp3 to be applied or not
bool IsActiveFalse = (LocationId != 0 && ActiveId == 2) || stats == "unsubscribe" || (ActiveId == 2 && stats == "subscribe"); //for comp3 to be false
bool DateApplied = LocationId == 0 || (LocationId != 0 && stats == "subscribe");
```

Then your `data.Where` for all cases except `6` and `9` can be simplified like this:

```
data.Where(x => (x.LocationId == LocationId || LocationIdNotApplied) //comp1
  && x.IsRemoved == false //comp2
  && ((x.IsActive == !IsActiveFalse) || IsActiveNotApplied) //comp3
  && (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || !DateApplied)) //comp4
```

This is a significant simplification for 12 cases becoming 1 case, and you only need to add the additional two cases, totalling in 3 cases rather than the original 14 cases!

---

#### Putting Them together into code

```
public DataTable GetCustomers(int LocationId, int ActiveId, string stats)
{
    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var data = from c in context.Customers
                   where c.Removed == false
                   select new
                   {
                       FullName = c.FullName,
                       c.CustomerID,
                       c._Location.Name,
                       c.IsActive,
                       c.SubscribeDate,
                       c.Removed
                   };

        bool LocationIdNotApplied = LocationId == 0; //for comp1
        bool IsActiveNotApplied = LocationId != 0 && (ActiveId < 0 || ActiveId > 2 || stats = "subscribe"); //for comp3 to be applied or not
        bool IsActiveFalse = (LocationId != 0 && ActiveId == 2) || stats == "unsubscribe" || (ActiveId == 2 && stats == "subscribe"); //for comp3 to be false
        bool DateApplied = LocationId == 0 || (LocationId != 0 && stats == "subscribe");

        if(LocationId == 0 && ActiveId == 1 && stats == "all"){ //case 6
            return MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                     data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == true) || (x.Removed == false) || (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false)));          
        } else if (LocationId == 0 && ActiveId == 2 && stats == "all"){ //case 9
            return MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                     data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false) && (x.Removed == false)));
        } else { //other cases
            return MyContext.CopyToDataTable(
                     data.Where(x => (x.LocationId == LocationId || LocationIdNotApplied) //comp1
                       && x.IsRemoved == false //comp2
                       && ((x.IsActive == !IsActiveFalse) || IsActiveNotApplied) //comp3
                       && (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || !DateApplied))) //comp4
        }
    }        
}
```

---

#### Last Notes

Your case 6 actually seems strange to me:

```
data.Where(x => (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == true) || (x.Removed == false) || (x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7) || x.IsActive == false)));
```

Note that you have both `x.IsActive == true` and `x.IsActive == false` for `x.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)`. And you combine it with `||`. This is like saying:

```
(A || true) || (A || false)
```

And will always `return true` no matter what. You might want to check again and you may even simplify further/

---

#### Last Remarks and Apologize

Thus goes my solution for this case without `PredicateBuilder` - it requires careful and "systematic" (or, what I actually mean is step by step) analysis on all possible cases.

I have to apologize the OP because I **cannot fully test** the code which I have proposed for lacking of complete testing resources (unlike the OP).

But if the OP finds that there is a case which I miss to handle **or** is not put by the OP in the original question, at the very least, the steps presented in my solution above should *still be useful* for the OP to make his/her own careful analysis for his/her actual cases.

Comment: I was thinking to do similar analysis. But seeing what you did, I'm happy that I don't have to! Respect for reverse engineering so unclear implementation which even seems to not matching the requirements described (or vice versa). +1

Comment: @IvanStoev Hi, it is you again. ;) good to see you. Thanks. I also like to decompose complex problems like this so smaller chunks for optimization.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detail and nice answer.i will definetely test your code and will let you know if there is any problem

Comment: @Learning sure. :) Nevertheless, please check what I mention on your case `6`... You can even further optimize the code if my conjecture be true

Comment: @Learning hei, thanks for the bounty! :) Does it mean that you *accept* my answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize search conditions in GetCustomer method. Please take a look Linqkit

**Here basic example**

http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/

**Using PredicateBuilder**

Here's how to solve the preceding example with PredicateBuilder:

```
IQueryable<Product> SearchProducts (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Product>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Description.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Products.Where (predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would not use `DataTable` anymore but create a ViewModel like this:

```
public class CustomerVm
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID  { get; set; }
    public string LocationName  { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive  { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubscribeDate  { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a basic query for grabbing the customers:

```
var data = from c in context.Customers
           where c.Removed == false;
```

Manipulate the *where* condition of your query according to your dropdown values:

```
if(ActiveId == 1)
{
    data = data.Where(c => c.IsActive);    
}
else if(ActiveId == 1)
{
    data = data.Where(c => c.IsActive);  
}

if (LocationId != 0)
{
    data = data.Where(c => c.LocationId == LocationId);  
}

if (stats == "subscribe")
{
    data = data.Where(c => c.IsActive 
      && c.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));  
}
else if (stats == "unbsubscribe")
{
    data = data.Where(c => !c.IsActive 
      && c.SubscribeDate >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7));  
}
```

In the end, execute the query and return the results as ViewModels:

```
return data.Select(c => new CustomerVm {
    FullName = c.FullName,
    CustomerId = ...
});
```

Comment: I have asked that only how to handle 3 filters and optimize the code and whether it is datatable or view model will not make any difference

Comment: Apart from that on page load event when all my 3 dropdown values are "All" then data coming are not appropriate as compared to when i set Active=1 and stats=all

Comment: View model = code optimization. All I wanted to show you was that you can chain your filters by overriding the same query. You have independent filters, therefor there is no need to write this nested if-statements.

Comment: Then how to filter records by removing this unexpected nested if  conditions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a different approach more scalable. A real big improvement in performance is to actually perform this filtering in pure SQL and only move the matching data to your application logic.

I was able to make this kind of queries 100x faster (using Oracle) by:

- adding a pl/sql procedure which accepts search criteria
- building a dynamic SQL statement and bind the search criteria there
- ensure that there are no "empty criteria", i.e. if location is not set, we don't build where (location=in_location or in_location is null)
- this gives a few fixed SQLs which text and execution plan will be cached

More info on the basics at https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1669972300346534908

Databases are built for doing data access, filtering and data joining *very well* on zillions of records. I found leveraging this gives a competitive advantage over any ORM tool which comes with serious limitations (where you give up the *whole* power of database side processing, you give up *all* advanced SQLs such as partitioning, and you *can't* access to technologies like Oracle text because you can't control query relaxation).